# Is there a way in Kubernetes to get the deployment name from Helm as an environment variable?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Is there any way to expose the deployment name from helm to a container? It is usually available as part of the hostname, but I'd rather not parse that if I can help it.

I know you can set certain metadata as specific environment variables according to the docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/
However, that doesn't seem to include deployment name directly. Is there a way to get this info?

Comment: Are you thinking like this? https://github.com/eclipse-iofog/iofog-operator/blob/develop/deploy/operator.yaml#L51

Comment: Is that exposing the deployment name? Looks like it's just the pod name....

Comment: Sorry I meant would this approach work for you? I can check whether deployment name is attainable.

Comment: metadata.name would suffice for you - just remove the replica set suffix and pod suffix e.g.  `<deployment_name>-<replica_set_hash>-<pod_hash>`. Let me know if this works and I can make an answer

Comment: @Serge that's what I was trying to avoid having to parse, if you read the question. Also your first question was answered in the question as well, I thought.

Comment: Yes sorry, I was not sure what you meant by `part of the hostname` in your question.

Answer (score 5):

You can't directly echo the deployment name into an environment variable, but you can duplicate the deployment name, including whatever template code generated it.

For example, let's say your deployment looks like the [standard template](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/pkg/chartutil/create.go#L242):

```yaml
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "chartname.fullname" . }}
```

In the pod spec part of the deployment, you can repeat that same invocation to get the same name.

```yaml
env:
  - name: DEPLOYMENT_NAME
    value: {{ include "chartname.fullname" . }}
```

You'd have to manually include this in your YAML, or in a set of standard environment variables in the `_helpers.tpl` file.  It will produce the correct values if you change the Helm release name and get a different deployment name.  It won't produce the correct values if you change the name at the top of the YAML file and forget to update it in the second place.